# Problem with position:absolute on input

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SZYUe/) code :

```
<div class="areaButton">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">                 
</div>

.areaButton
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:18px;
    margin-right:18px;
    background-color:red;
}

.areaButton input
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

but as you can see, the Input doesnt "feel" the container (where is the `background-color:red;`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `position:absolute` removes the element from the [document flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow), meaning it basically doesn't occupy any space. Since this is the only element in the div, and there is no height width or padding on it, it doesn't take up any space either, so you cannot see the background.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers insert default margin and padding on some elements, that's what [CSS resets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) are for.

As you mark your input element as `position: absolute`, it gets taken out of the [page flow](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/layout/), and the container won't expand to fit the element. You have to add height to the `.areaButton` element to see the background.

See my update:

> http://jsfiddle.net/SZYUe/1/

Answer (score 2):

put a height to the .areaButton div the same with the height of the input.

```
.areaButton
{
   height: <same height as the input>;
   ....
}
```

or put another element inside the div

```
<div class="areaButton">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">  
    <span>&nbsp;</span>               
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <div class="areaButton">
>     <div> THis is the are around the button</div>
>     <input type="submit" value="Add">                 
> </div>
>
>
> .areaButton
> {
>     float:left;
>     position:relative;
>     width:200px;
>     margin-left:18px;
>     margin-right:18px;
>     background-color:red;
> }
>
> .areaButton input
> {
>     position:absolute;
>     right:0px;
>     top:0px;
> background-color:red;
> border:5px solid yellow;
> }
> ```